# Trouble with an integral

Tags: integration

I've difficulties calculating the following sum of integrals:

$$\int_{0}^{\sqrt2}{{\int_{0}^{x}xe^{{(x^2+y^2)}^{3/2}}dy} dx}+\int_{\sqrt2}^{2}{{\int_{0}^{\sqrt{4-x^2}}xe^{{(x^2+y^2)}^{3/2}}dy} dx}$$

My suggestion would be to rewrite this as:
$$\int_{0}^{2}{{\int_{0}^{(1/4)π}r^2cos(φ)e^{r^3}dφ} dr}$$

However, the solution manual says the following with respect to $r$:
$$0\leq{r}\leq\sqrt2$$
But I can't figure out why. Is there anyone who can give me a hint, or could it be that the solution manual is wrong?

Comment: You need to reverse the order of integration.

Comment: That is not useful here.

Comment: @Dr.MV You're right. I see that it leads to an integral of the form $\int e^{cy^3}dy$.

Comment: The solution manual is wrong.  The domain is a quater circle.  By the way, rhe upper limit should be $\pi/4$, not $1/4\pi$.

Comment: @johnwaylandbayles Yes, the integrand won't be a perfect differential .  The domain is just a quater circle and polar coordinates work fine here.

Comment: @Dr.MV Thanks for your reply, I see that I forgot the brackets :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Draw the region of integration - it ends up just being a sector of a circle.  The integral is equal to, in polars,

$$\int_0^2 dr \, r^2 \,  e^{r^3} \int_0^{\pi/4} d\phi \, \cos{\phi} = \frac{e^8-1}{3 \sqrt{2}}$$

Comment: You've got the same answer as I do, which indeed implies that the solution manual is wrong. Thanks for your comment.